# Parsing csv data - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm receiving data from the CSV file as

```
SERVICE_ID‡WEIGHT_ID‡DISTANCE_ID‡BASE_PRICE‡IDENTIFIER
PARCEL‡W0‡‡0.00‡N
PARCEL‡W1‡‡19.00‡N
```

Upon extracting this file with the help of `CsvToListConverter()` I was able to print the data as

```
[SERVICE_ID, WEIGHT_ID, DISTANCE_ID, BASE_PRICE, IDENTIFIER
PARCEL, W0, , 0.00, N
PARCEL, W1, , 19.00, N]
```

So I just removed the first row by using the range property `result.removeRange(0, 4);` and printed the result as

```
[PARCEL, W0, , 0.00, N
PARCEL, W1, , 19.00, N]
```

**Actually the 4 indexes is being taken by both N & Parcel together**
If i print result[4], I'm getting as `NParcel` where in it should be only `N`

This is the model representation

```
class mode {
 final String type;
 final String code;
 final String isSent;
 final String price;
 final String delivered;

mode(this.type, this.code, this.isSent, this.price, this.delivered)
}
```

How to extract the data?
**Note There is no `Comma` symbol after N nor any new line `\n` code**

Comment: I just read your note, the data you're showing are strings? I mean according to your note is the 5th item in the list `"N PARCEL"` ? , and is your third item `""` ?

Comment: I think there must be a newline character after the `N` which is why `PARCEL` appears on the next line. You need to try experimenting with the `eol` setting of `CsvToListConvertor()` - try `\\n` instead of the the default `\\r\\n`. You need to get your list to come out as `[[SERVICE_ID, ....], [PARCEL, ....]]` - note how the inner `[ ]` are inside an outer `[ ]`.

Comment: Please update the question with the result of `print(utf8.encode(csv));` where csv is what you are passing as the input to `CsvToListConvertor`

Comment: @tareqalbeesh the result I'm getting is **0 index -> PARCEL, 1 index -> W0, 2 index -> "", 3 index -> 0.00 & in 4 index -> NPARCEL**, where in the 4 th index should have been just N

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it does not work for you, but this example works without problems.

```dart
import 'package:fast_csv/fast_csv_ex.dart' as fast_csv_ex;

void main(List<String> args) {
  final records = fast_csv_ex.parse(_data, separator: '‡');
  final r1 = records[1];
  final r2 = records[2];
  print(r1[4]);
  print(r2[0]);
  print(r2);
}

const _data = '''
SERVICE_ID‡WEIGHT_ID‡DISTANCE_ID‡BASE_PRICE‡IDENTIFIER
PARCEL‡W0‡‡0.00‡N
PARCEL‡W1‡‡19.00‡N''';
```

Output:

```
N
PARCEL
[PARCEL, W1, , 19.00, N]
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions, finally solved it by using the string split method by
`tariffFields.toString().replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "").split("\n");`